# Java обработка исключений при вводе недопустимых значений

Tags: java, исключения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обработать исключение при вводе числа, вместо строки?(Там автоматически созданный кэтч блок, как вы можете заметить).

И вопрос про обработку исключения, когда ввели символ, вместо номера этажа. Я его написала, НО, если я ввожу символ, то меня уже просят ввести следующие данные, а неправильные данные с номером этажа остаются. Конечно, я могу просто осуществить выход из программы в этом кэтч блоке, а как осуществить так, чтобы у пользователя ,так скажем, был еще один шанс ввести номер этажа?Т.е. снова вернуться к try блоку ?

UPD:вроде бы со второй частью вопроса разобралась с помощью введения доп. переменной типа boolean. Но первый вопрос всё ещё остается открытым.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double number = 0,number2=0;
int number1=0;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Введите название города");
String s="";
try {
    s = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    System.out.println ("Введите номер этажа ");
    number1 = scanner.nextInt();
    }
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println ("Вероятно, вы ввели недопустимый формат данных ");
    scanner.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы лучше выносил такую логику в отдельный метод. Примерно так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    
    private final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String city = input("Введите название города : ", v -> v);
        Integer numb = input("Введите номер этажа : ", Integer::valueOf);
        
        System.out.println("Город : " + city);
        System.out.println("Этаж : " + numb);
    }
    
    private static <T> T input(String message, Function<String, T> converter) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(message);
                return converter.apply(scanner.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Вероятно, вы ввели недопустимый формат данных ");
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: А скомпилируется? return вроде не всегда достижим, а джава на такое ругается

Comment: @Sergey Zh скомпилируется, там весь метод внутри бесконечного цикла.